# How can I set an Item as Default in Variant-Management's manage dialogue?

Tags: sapui5

I'm using:

- SAP UI5 version 1.38.8
- [sap.ui.comp.variants.VariantManagement](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.variants.VariantManagement)

My problem is that I can't set an item programmatically so that the item is shown as 'selected' in the management dialog.

It works in the select dialogue (or popup), as shown below:
[image: figure1]

However, it doesn't work in the "variants manage" dialog, as you can see in here
[image: figure2]

Unfortunately, I need to use version 1.38.8 (because of restrictions by customer's environment). Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

`variantManagment.setDefaultVariantKey(item.VariantId);`

after Variants were loaded.
I don't know why it didn't work at my first tries.